# Is it recommended to use the using keyword in a function?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using, using-directives

I'm editing a large source file that was authored by someone else. They didn't put the `using namespace xxx` directive in file scope and I don't want to add it at file scope and edit all occurrences of `xxx::typename` to `typename`. But, at the same time, I don't want to keep typing all these long nested namespace names in a new function that I'm writing in this file, so I decided to use the using directive inside the function like so:

```
void foo()
{
  using namspace namesp1::namesp2;

  // do foo stuff
}
```

This code compiles fine, but I'm not sure if there are any gotchas. Are there any rules that dictate when file or function scope should be preferred?

Comment: Seems fine to me

Comment: FWIW I always prefer to fully qualify the name.  If the names are long, you can make an alias to make your life easier.  When you just import all the names you have a chance that there can be a conflict.

Comment: Depends on your team's conventions, or what you are comfortable with.  It's perfectly legit in the language.  My concern is that it may pull in far more symbols than you need, and as things evolve may pull in an identifier that collides.  When I have `using` identifiers from another namespace, my preference is pulling in the identifiers explicitly (e.g., `using std::cout;`), rather than the entire namespace (e.g., `using namespace std;`).

Comment: *I don't want to add it at file scope and edit all occurrences of xxx::typename to typename* If I'm not mistaken, you should still be able to use the fully qualified name even if you use `using`.

Comment: @Chipster: Correct. The `using` helps with unqualified name lookup; qualified name lookup is not affected. (Unless you have something as awful as `namespace xxx { int std;`. Don't do that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are gotchas with it as such. Whatever the problem exists if you put `using namespace blah;` at file scope, still exists but is limited to just the function.
It's generally a reasonable compromise when you had to type very long type names (`foo::bar::blah::something::thingy var;`).

A slightly better option is to use an alias:

```
void foo()
{
    using p1p2 = namesp1::namesp2;

    // do stuff
}
```

Then you can use `p1p2::thingy` which makes namespace collisions even less likely.

Comment: This is exactly my problem, there are numerous nested namespaces. I usually define aliases to make my STL data members more readable, but using them in a function to prevent tedious typing works just as well. I'll adopt this approach.

Comment: The using keyword is not working in this context. I think you meant to say `namespace p1p2 = namesp1::namesp2`

Comment: @DigitalEye `using` to create alias is valid since C++11. What you have would work too.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias has few examples.

Answer (score 3):

There are several bad consequences of pulling in a complete namespace. Consider this example

```
void foo() {
    using namspace A;
    using namspace B;
    bar();              
    A::moo();           
    B::moo();  
};
```

- It is harder to see from what namespace a symbol is coming from. Is `bar` from `A` or from `B` ? Or perhaps from the global namespace?
- Symbols (eg `moo`) being declared in more than one namespace you are `using` you have to fully qualify anyhow.
- Lets say `bar` is from `A`, if at some later point `B` gets a `bar` added the code will break

Better use only what you need:

```
void foo() {
    using A::bar;
    bar();
}
```